# TinyMCE fails silently

Tags: javascript, debugging, tinymce

How do I set debug mode or similar in TinyMCE?

When there are errors (for example undefined references) in custom setup functions or somewhere else, all my script stops and I don't see a single line appearing in the console.

Didn't find anything searching, maybe I'm not seeing the obvious again... can't be that difficult...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Unfortunately, there is only the way of using try-catch blocks in custom setup functions.